# Pronouncing h as /x/?

Tags: phonology, velar, frontness-backness

I am curious about phonics and wonder if pronouncing the /h/ sound as /x/ would be distinguishable. This is basically turning a k into a fricative, and this is basically h fronting.

Comment: Sure, plenty of languages distinguish [h] from [x]. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Could a typical English speaker notice it, @Draconis? And that too. I mean what are a few languages that do?

Comment: @NumberFile I'm probably not a typical English speaker, but I sure do notice it when Spanish or Greek speakers pronounce English /h/ as [x] due to lacking [h] but having [x] in their native languages.

Comment: One of the main difficulties of teaching English to the speakers of the Slavic languages is teaching them to pronounce [h], since no Slavic language has this sound, all the Slavs tend to pronounce [x] instead, which adds a Slavic accent to their English speech. And yes, substitution of [h] by [x] is well distinguishable by ear.

Comment: I added an upvote to this question because I think it deserves an answer, which Draconis has thoughtfully provided.   @ Number File:  Are you familiar with the notion of phonemes?

Answer (score 4):

From the comments:

> Could a typical English speaker notice it [and] what are a few languages that do?

For the first part, I would say **yes** from anecdotal evidence. They would probably still understand you, but it would be easily noticed. Native speakers of Spanish and Modern Greek, for example, often pronounce English `/h/` as `[x]`, and are understood just fine (but with a noticeable accent—to me this is one of the most distinctive parts of a Greek accent). It's also worth noting that `/x/` often becomes `/k/` rather than `/h/` when loaned into English, as in the name "Khalil".

For the second part, many Semitic languages (e.g. Hebrew, Arabic) contrast the two. Languages in the Pacific Northwest also tend to have lots of dorsal fricatives, like Tlingit, which contrasts `/x/`, `/χ/`, and `/h/` (plus some labialized and ejective versions). If you want to stick to Europe, Standard German has both `/x~ç/` and `/h/`, though `/x~ç/` usually occurs in coda position (and is realized as `[ç]` when it's not).